# NSMutableArray, removeFromArray and release, why does this crash?

Tags: crash, nsmutablearray, release, memory-leaks

The following method is used to cleanup a journal of its empty pages at the end.

```
// self.pages property declaratioN, this is on the header
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *pages;

// method that crashes
- (void)cleanup {

    NSMutableArray *pagesToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int n = [self.pages count]-1; n >= 0; n--) {
        JournalPage *page = [self.pages objectAtIndex:n];
        if (![page isEmpty]) {
            break;
        } else {
            if (([self.pages count] - ([pagesToRemove count] + 1) > 2)) {
                [pagesToRemove addObject:page];
            } else {
                break;
            }               
        }

    }

    if ([pagesToRemove count] % 2 != 0) {
        [pagesToRemove removeLastObject];
    }
    [self.pages removeObjectsInArray:pagesToRemove];
    [pagesToRemove release]; // this line makes the app crash
}
```

Releasing `pagesToRemove` causes a crash. The crash happens also if I remove the `[pageToRemove release]`, and use instead autorelease when I alloc/init the `NSMutableArray` instance.

Without releasing `pageToRemove` the code works, but I see a leak, and clang analyzer also sees it.
Is this code leaking; if not, why?

Comment: Is it possible that the pages themselves are over-released somewhere? So basically once you remove them from self.pages they're essentially destroyed, then when pagesToRemove gets released, they get extra release messages and cause a crash. That'd be my guess based solely on what's presented here. So take a look at how you're creating the page objects themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your crasher:

```
[pageToRemove release]; // this line makes the app crash
```

Note that it says pageToRemove, not page**s**ToRemove. ;)

Comment: You're right, ut unluckily it's a typo I made here re-instating the code for stackoverflow; the crash happens anyhow. But thanks, I'm editing now to fix the bug